# JSoup Failed Scraping Image URL from Google Shopping

Tags: jsoup

I tried to get the URL of the image from Google Shopping search result.
My code in acquiring image url is like below:

```
Element image = el.getElementsByClass("TL92Hc").get(0);
System.out.println(image.attr("src"));
```

What I got is deprecated version of the src value, which is like below:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
```

I know that the length of image url that generated by Google Shopping is very - very long (around 12047 characters).

Is there anyway that can make Jsoup NOT deprecating the result?

Answer (score 0):

It's not truncated as it ends with `==` like most base64 strings. Also it's valid 1x1 px gif image (it opens in browser when you paste `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==` into address bar.

So my guess is that this page contains more than one image with class `TL92Hc` or this image is only a placeholder and the real image is loaded dynamically with JavaScript.